# show that $A \cap B$ is a normal subgroup of $B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $A$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $B$ is a subgroup of $G$.  Please help me to show that $A \cap B$ is a normal subgroup of $B$.

I know that since $B$ is subgroup of $G$, it has identity element, $e$ which makes it not to be an empty set.  The same applies to $A$, which is a normal subgroup of $G$.  Therefore, $e$ is an element of $A \cap B$.

Comment: Can you write down a definition of normal subgroup?  What do you need to show in order to conclude that $A \cap B \unlhd B$?

Comment: @Sammy Black Dfinition of Normal Subgroup : let B be a subgroup of G , then B is called a Normal subgroup of G if and only if g^-1 b g is an element of B for all b element of B and g element of G denoted by B⊴G.

Comment: Yes, @nhlanhla.  So, in order to show that $A \cap B \unlhd B$, let $x \in A \cap B$ and $b \in B$, and convince yourself that the conjugate $bxb^{-1} \in A \cap B$ also.  (You will have to use the fact that $A \unlhd G$.)

Comment: @Sammy Black tnx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably already have proved that intersection of subgroups is a subgroup (i.e. neither the group operation nor its inverse lead out: $x,y\in A\cap B\implies  xy\in A\cap B,\ x^{-1}\in A\cap B$).
2. What is left to prove, is that $A\cap B$ is also closed under *conjugations* with elements of $B$ (this would mean that $A\cap B\,\lhd B$), that is, check that
   $bxb^{-1}\in A\cap B\ $ whenever $x\in A\cap B$ and $b\in B$.